# Laravel Eloquent query for join with like

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have this raw query but I'm struggling to convert it to eloquent.  Below is my raw sql.  I cannot use DB:select because i'm using paginate at the end.

```
select * from orders
join users on orders.user_id = users.id
where orders.id = $search
or orders.reference_no like '%$search%'
or users.name like '%$search%'

public function customer()
{
return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
}

 $orders = Order::where('reference_no', 'LIKE', "%$search%")
            ->orWhere('reference_no',$search)
            ->orWhere('id',$search)
            ->whereHas('customer', function ($query) use ($search) {
                $query->where('name', 'like', '%$search%');
            })
            ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Show us your models and what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result = Order::select('orders.*')
       ->join('users', 'orders.user_id', '=', 'user.users.id')
       ->where(function($q) {
              $q->where('orders.id', $search)
                ->orWhere('orders.reference_no', 'like', "%$search%")
                ->orWhere('users.name', 'like', "%$search%") ;
              })
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   $result = Order::select('orders.*')
           ->join('users', 'orders.user_id', '=', 'user.users.id')
           ->where(function($q) use ($search){
                  $q->where('orders.id', $search)
                    ->orWhere('orders.reference_no','like', '%$search%')
                    ->orWhere('users.name','like', '%$search%') ;
                  })
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Pavel and Unai.  Based on your answer manage to do this.  Need to do a 'use'  and in te orWhere I need to concat '%' to the actual $search variable.  If I dont have concat '.'  literal search is shown in the query

```
            $orders = Order::select('orders.*')
            ->join('users', 'orders.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->where(function($q) use ($search) {
                $q->where('orders.id', $search)
                    ->orWhere('orders.reference_no', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
                    ->orWhere('users.name', 'like', '%' . $search .'%') ;
            })
            ->paginate(10);
```